# Почему игрок останавливается только когда выполнено самое последнее условие?

Tags: java

Написал код на остановку,но почему выполняется ТОЛЬКО последнее условие?

```
for(Point p : level.brickCoords) { 
        if(new Rectangle((int) (newX), (int) (newY), SPRITE_SCALE + 14, SPRITE_SCALE + 14).intersects(new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, level.SCALE,level.SCALE)) && rotate == rotate.NORTH) {
           speed = 0;

        if(rotate == rotate.EAST || rotate == rotate.WEST || rotate == rotate.SOUTH) { 
           speed = 2.1f;        
         }  

        }else if(new Rectangle((int) (newX), (int) (newY),SPRITE_SCALE + 14, SPRITE_SCALE + 14).intersects(new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, level.SCALE,level.SCALE)) && rotate == rotate.SOUTH) {
           speed = 0;      
        if(rotate == rotate.EAST || rotate == rotate.WEST || rotate == rotate.NORTH) { 
           speed = 2.1f;       

        }   

        }else if(new Rectangle((int) (newX), (int) (newY),SPRITE_SCALE + 14, SPRITE_SCALE + 14).intersects(new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, level.SCALE,level.SCALE)) && rotate == rotate.EAST) {
           speed = 0;  
        if(rotate == rotate.EAST || rotate == rotate.NORTH || rotate == rotate.SOUTH) { 
           speed = 2.1f;       

        }    
        }else if(new Rectangle((int) (newX), (int) (newY),SPRITE_SCALE + 14, SPRITE_SCALE + 14).intersects(new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, level.SCALE,level.SCALE)) && rotate == rotate.WEST) {
          speed = 0;
         }  
        if(rotate == rotate.NORTH || rotate == rotate.EAST || rotate == rotate.SOUTH) { 
          speed = 2.1f;    

         }
```

Comment: Скажите, Вам знакомо слово рефакторинг? У вас гора дублирующего кода. Избавьтесь от него для начала, глядишь, все и заработает...

Comment: Скажите, "специалист", что обозначает гора в вашем понимание? все что повторяется это 'new Rectangle((int) (newX), (int) (newY),SPRITE_SCALE + 14, SPRITE_SCALE + 14).intersects(new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, level.SCALE,level.SCALE))', конечно можно сделать так 'if(new Rectangle((int) (newX), (int) (newY),SPRITE_SCALE + 14, SPRITE_SCALE + 14).intersects(new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, level.SCALE,level.SCALE)) && rotate == rotate.NORTH и т.д)', но мне кажется, со всем капельку, что он прилипнет к кубику, пожалуйста разберитесь в коде и потом лишь пишите,рефакторинг тут никак не поможет(да он и не нужен)

Comment: Ну нельзя, так нельзя... Но вы все равно посмотрите, что такое полиморфизм. Если на ваш взгляд 6 условных операторов, 4 из которых вложенных , помещенных в цикл,  не требуют рефакторинга, тогда пишите и дальше в таком же духе. С другой стороны вы правы. Этот код не требует рефакторинга. Он настолько плохой, что рефакторингу не поддается. Его нужно просто удалить и написать заново. Вы можете найти здесь ошибку, вопрос в том, что вы будете делать, когда сложность задачи возрастет в сотни раз (а в реальной разработке так и есть)